# Cannot set properties of undefined in key-value store

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, typeerror, key-value

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="./framework.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p f-text="name"></p>
  <script>
    Framework.store('name', 'Joe');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((element) => {
  if (element.hasAttribute('f-text')) {
    const textValue = element.getAttribute('f-text');
    
    element.innerHTML = window.fStore[textValue];
  }
});

window.Framework = {
  store: (key, value = '') => {
    if (value === '') {
      return window.fStore[key];
    }

    window.fStore[key] = value;
  }
}
```

But get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
    at Object.store (/framework.js:15:24)
    at /:12:15
```

I want the page to render 'Joe' by getting the key from `f-text`, finding the key's value in `window.fStore`, then setting the `element.innerHTML` as the value. `Framework.store()` takes a key and a value, if there is no value it returns the value from the key in `window.fStore`, if there is then it sets `window.fStore[key]` to the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether `window.fStore` exists first.

```js
window.Framework = {
  store: (key, value = '') => {
    if(!window.fStore) window.fStore = {}
    if (value === '') {
      return window.fStore[key];
    }
    window.fStore[key] = value;
  }
}
Framework.store('name', 'Joe');

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((element) => {
  if (element.hasAttribute('f-text')) {
    const textValue = element.getAttribute('f-text');
    element.innerHTML = window.fStore[textValue];
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p f-text="name"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't give me an error anymore but page stays blank.

Comment: @TacoSnack move your script tag with the JS file to after the `p` tag. It's probably because the element wasn't in the DOM when you tried selecting them.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: @TacoSnack also, call `store` before selecting the element.  Basically, just copy the JS in the snippet into the file.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to wait till the window loads first. Some browsers will give you a headache if you dont

```js
window.addEventListener('load', e=>{
  window.Framework = {
    store: (key, value = '') => {
      if(!window.fStore)
        window.fStore = {};
      if (value === '')
        return window.fStore[key];
      window.fStore[key] = value;
    }
  }
  window.Framework.store('name', 'Joe');

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((element) => {
    if (element.hasAttribute('f-text'))
      element.innerHTML = window.fStore[element.getAttribute('f-text')];
  });
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error: `ReferenceError: Framework is not defined
    at /:12:5`

Comment: Sorry hope the edit fixed it

Comment: I have the `Framework.store()` in the `<script>` tag, not in the JS file.